# How can I run different functions when clicking and double clicking using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Simply put:

1. what I want:
   you click something calls function `xxx()`, while you double click calls another `function yyy()`
2. when I put `onclick` and `ondblclick` together only `xxx()` executed, so how do I achieve the similar effect?

   Thanks!!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546040/how-to-use-both-onclick-and-ondblclick-on-an-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, in some browsers, your onclick handler grabs the first click of the pair, and the ondblclick handler never sees the action.  In other browsers the click is seen twice and the double click as well.  The potential timing for a double click will vary by operating system, browser, and user configuration.

Handling this in a portable way is, to say the least, difficult.

I would recommend only having click handlers.  But have the click handler set a variable, and a timeout.  If the timeout is hit without a second click, do the onclick action.  If a second click happens in that time, make sure that the timeout will do nothing and do the ondblclick action.  The drawback is that this means that your double clicks won't respect the rules of the local operating system, browser, and user configuration.

Comment: Does jQuery emulate click correctly with `.bind("dblclick", ...)` in a cross-browser compliant manner?

Comment: @Raynos: There is a big fat warning in http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/ that very strongly suggests not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
var dbclkTimeout=-1;
somelement.onclick=function(){
  if(dbclkTimeout==-1)
    dbclkTimeout=setTimeout(function(){onclickcallback();dbclkTimeout=-1;} , 200);
  else {
    clearTimeout(dbclkTimeout);
    dbclkTimeout=-1;
    ondbclickcallback();
  }
}
```