# Call ondblclick without calling onclick-event

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a simple solution without jquery, inside HTML-tags, that will call the `ondblclick` without causing `onclick` to happen too?

This always closes the window although it should just show the alert:

```
<a href="#" ondblclick="alert('dbl')" onclick="window.close();">X</a>
```

(it only works in a javascript popup, cause you cannot close the main window with `window.close();`)

Comment: If you don't need the close window click return it false. Otherwise you need a function to keep track of how many clicks happened before executing the functions bound to them

Comment: Here's the best idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546040/how-to-use-both-onclick-and-ondblclick-on-an-element -- tl;dr - Set a short timeout for single click so it doesn't hijack your dblclick

Comment: would this work without using a timeout to catch the singleclick? Because, I don't want to change the behaviour of the whole site just because of this one button.

Comment: Don't think so...that onclick is going to fire regardless then

Comment: Maybe a better solution would be a `onCTRLclick` handler, that would catch the singleclick with the CTRL-Key pressed at the same time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700114/catch-onclick-event-with-ctrl-pressed

Comment: From jQuery docs but related:"It is inadvisable to bind handlers to both the click and dblclick events for the same element. The sequence of events triggered varies from browser to browser, with some receiving two click events before the dblclick and others only one. Double-click sensitivity (maximum time between clicks that is detected as a double click) can vary by operating system and browser, and is often user-configurable."

Comment: what would be the point of both a `click` and `ondblclick`???

Comment: Have you checked my answer ?

Comment: @KitePlayer: that looks good, But I solved it by using CTRL+click instead of dblclick now. Maybe someone else can check your answer.

Comment: @rubo77 can you post your answer ? This may be useful to others or accept any other answers which you find useful .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that every solution will also have the problem with the doubleclick timeout-length varying on user preferences described by **Irvin Dominin aka Edward** in the comment above:

> From jQuery docs but related: *"It is inadvisable to bind handlers to
>   both the click and dblclick events for the same element. The sequence
>   of events triggered varies from browser to browser, with some
>   receiving two click events before the dblclick and others only one.
>   Double-click sensitivity (maximum time between clicks that is detected
>   as a double click) can vary by operating system and browser, and is
>   often user-configurable."*

I abandoned using doubleclick and used CTRL+click instead:

```
<a href="#" onclick="if(event.ctrlKey) { 
 alert('CTRL+Mouseclick'); return false; 
} else { window.close(); }">X</a>
```

see:

> [Catch onclick-event with CTRL pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700114/catch-onclick-event-with-ctrl-pressed)

Answer (score 5):

I have **solved** this with the below code,

```
<a id="press" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="singleClick(event)"
    ondblclick="doubleClick(event)">Click here</a>

<div id="log"></div>
```

My **JavaScript** will be ,

```
    var timer;
    var status = 1;

    function singleClick(event) {
        status = 1;
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            if (status == 1) {
                document.getElementById("log").innerHTML ='I  am single click !';
            }
        }, 500);

    }

    function doubleClick(event) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        status = 0;
        document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = 'I  am a double  click!';
    }
```

Please let me know the status.Hope this helps.

Comment: My guess is that your solution will also have the problem with the doubleclick timeout-length varying on user preferences described by **Irvin Dominin aka Edward** in the comment above. I abandoned using doubleclick and used CTRL+click instead

Comment: I have successfully implemented this in my project and works without any problem. DbClick must me little quick . If you leave some gap , normally it was considered as two single click.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a situation difficult to handle, you can use a timeout, but you can't be sure about the correct behaviour.

In the jQuery (but vanilla too) docs there is an important note, that tell us to avoid the handling of both single and double click:

> It is inadvisable to bind handlers to both the click and dblclick
>   events for the same element. The sequence of events triggered varies
>   from browser to browser, with some receiving two click events before
>   the dblclick and others only one. Double-click sensitivity (maximum
>   time between clicks that is detected as a double click) can vary by
>   operating system and browser, and is often user-configurable.

So in think that in short:

1. if you can refactor your UI with a single handler
2. alternatively use a timeout as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546040/how-to-use-both-onclick-and-ondblclick-on-an-element), but will not be bulletproof

Answer (score 1):

JS:

```
var single;
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" 
  ondblclick="single=0; alert('dbl')" 
  onclick="single=1; setTimeout(function(){
    if (single) window.close();
  },300);">X</a>
```

Comment: This looks, like it would work. You add a timeout here after that you check if the single click remains single

Comment: Only remains a small fraction of users that are used to a really long double click time, longer than the 300 ms defined here

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems you want both to work depending on number of clicks, then it would be better to introduce a short timeout between clicks and run the respective functions accordingly. You may look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546040/how-to-use-both-onclick-and-ondblclick-on-an-element).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not what you want to do for your question, but here's a way to use a click and a double easily:

If you need to select an object with a click (or save a variable for example), you can use javascript to call a function in a "href".

Then you can use the "ondblclik ()" to directly edit the registry, without clicking the edit button.

The function in the "href" is always executed, so do not test it with "alert ()", you will not get a double click, as the message window will open. It runs 2 times, then perform an action that can be a problem, but not to save or update variables.

```js
function clickMe(c){
  var link = document.getElementById('link');
  link.innerHTML = "Clicked: "+c;
}
```

```html
<a id="link" href="javascript:clickMe(1);void(0);" ondblclick="clickMe(2);">Click Me</a>
```