# Catch onclick-event with CTRL pressed

Tags: javascript

Is there a simple solution without jquery, inside HTML-tags to catch a CTRL+Mouseclick?

It could look like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="if(ctrl_is_pressed()) alert('CTRL+Mouseclick');">X</a>
```

Comment: I asume this is to prevent the anchor opening in a new tab/window. Unless you have a **very good** reason for this, dont change browser behaviour. It will hurt the user experience more than it does any good

Comment: I want to use the X as a close button, except in case CTRL is pressed too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `event` object, there's a [`ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.ctrlKey) property.

```
<a href="#" onclick="if(event.ctrlKey) alert('CTRL+Mouseclick');">X</a>
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. I used it like this: `<a  href="#" onclick="if(event.ctrlKey) { alert('CTRL+Mouseclick'); return false; } else { window.close(); }">X</a>`