# ondblclick won't work on element with onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following problem:
I have an image.When the user clicks it it will display an alert box but I also want to remove it if the user double clicks it. I have the following markup but it is not working.

```
<h1>hello </h1>
            <img src="smile.png" class=" center-block" onclick="alert('Hello')" ondblclick="$('img').remove();">
```

The only working part is the alert button
Note: jquery is loaded

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330431/jquery-bind-double-click-and-single-click-separately

Comment: Why did you roll-back @Scimonster's correct edit? There is no `ondbclick` or `elemt`. To your question: you might want to detect the dbl-click yourself (using a timer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546040/how-to-use-both-onclick-and-ondblclick-on-an-element  that way you won't pre-maturely fire the blocking `alert()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for what you are trying to accomplish in your code:

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/gz4gst49/14/

With the code below placed in a script tag at the bottom of your body document you 
still use the alert if you want:

```
<script>


//the class to click on
var selector = ".center-block";

//set the doubleClicked variable to 0 meaning false
//in this example
var doubleClicked = 0;

//on single click function for selector class
$(selector).on("click",function(){//begin function


//use time out function to delay execution for specified amount
//of time in this case I used 2 seconds
setTimeout(function () {

    //if doubleClicked equals 0
    if (doubleClicked === 0){//begin if then

            //display alert
            alert("hello");

    }//end if then else

    }, 2000);//<--delay set for two seconds

});//end function

//on double click function
$(selector).on("dblclick",function(){//begin function

    //set doubleClicked to 1 
    doubleClicked = 1;

    //remove the img element
    $("img").remove();


});//end function

 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert):

> Dialog boxes are modal windows - they prevent the user from accessing the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed. For this reason, you should not overuse any function that creates a dialog box (or modal window).

If you're triggering an `alert()` on click, the UI will be disabled and you can not perform an immediate follow up click without closing the `alert()`. (*You should be hearing a warning sound*)

Answer (score 0):

don't use inline javascript when you want to specify element, in your something.js write:

```
$('.center-block').dbclick(function(){
  $('img').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to detect the dbl-click yourself (using a timer).

The basic concept in pure javascript works like this:

```html
<img class=" center-block" 
       src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pucwG.png" 
   onclick="clearTimeout(this.timer); //catch the second click of dbl-click
            this.timer=setTimeout(function(){ alert('Hello'); }, 250);" 
ondblclick="clearTimeout(this.timer); 
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);"
>
```

In this example we simply hook the timer-id (the return-value of `setTimeout`) to the originating element.
Passing an invalid ID to `clearTimeout` does not have any effect (and doesn't throw an exception), so we don't even need to check for it's existence.
A delay-time of 250 ms is usually enough (150ms is usually to short).

Note: is recommended to use more advanced methods to hook your events instead of in-lining them as you have done.