# dgrid rows and double click event

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, dom-events, double-click, dgrid

I have a [dgrid](http://dgrid.io/) table with a selection mode of **`toggle`**. One of my requirements is to implement a double click on a row to trigger a function.

Here is what I have:

```
grid.on('.dgrid-content .dgrid-row:dblclick', function () {
    window.alert('Hello world!');
});
```

The problem is that double-clicking also causes the [selection events](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v0.4.0/doc/components/mixins/Selection.md) `dgrid-select` and `dgrid-deselect` to fire as it is also registering two single clicks to select.

I have tried adding this code but it does not work as intended:

```
var timer;

grid.on('.dgrid-content .dgrid-row:click', function (event) {
    var row = this;
    if (timer) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        clearTimeout(timer);
    } else {
        timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
            // something to make the click go through?
            row.emit('something here');
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }, 250);
    }
});
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

I've consulted [How to use both onclick and ondblclick on an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546040/how-to-use-both-onclick-and-ondblclick-on-an-element) but the answers there did not seem to work in my case.

I've also looked at the misc utilities and perhaps it is the [`debounce`](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v0.4.0/doc/components/utilities/misc.md) function that I need but I am not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions `row` and `cell`  from Dgrid class:

```js
 define([
     "dojo/_base/declare",
     "dojo/_base/lang", // hitch
     "dgrid/OnDemandGrid"
 ], function (declare, lang, OnDemandGrid){
     return declare(OnDemandGrid, {

         _onSingleClickAction: function (event) {
             var row = this.row(event), // dgrid/Grid methods
                 cell = this.cell(event);

             /********************
             * WORKING WITH DATA *
             ********************/
         }, // _onSingleClickAction

         _onDblClickAction: function (event) {
             var row = this.row(event), // dgrid/Grid methods
                 cell = this.cell(event);

             /********************
             * WORKING WITH DATA *
             ********************/
         }, // _onDblClickAction

         postCreate: function () {
             this.inherited(arguments);

             this.on(".dgrid-content .dgrid-row:dblclick", lang.hitch(this, "_onDblClickAction"));
             this.on(".dgrid-content .dgrid-row:click", lang.hitch(this, "_onSingleClickAction"));
         } // postCreate
     }); // declare
 }); // define
```

Final class definition:

```js
 define([
     "dojo/_base/declare",
     "dojo/_base/lang", // hitch
     "dgrid/OnDemandGrid"
 ], function (declare, lang, OnDemandGrid){
     return declare(OnDemandGrid, {

         onDblClick: function (row) {  // empty method for definition in childs
             console.log(row.id);      // record id from the store
             console.log(row.data);    // full object from the store
             console.log(row.element); // DOM element
         },

         _onDblClick: function (event) { // private method
             this.onDblClick(this.row(event)); // extract data from event
         }, // _onDblClick

         postCreate: function () {
             this.inherited(arguments);

             this.on(".dgrid-content .dgrid-row:dblclick", lang.hitch(this, "_onDblClick"));
         } // postCreate
     }); // declare
 }); // define
```

[1] https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v1.2.1/doc/usage/Working-with-Events.md