# Perform double click on html element

Tags: html, vb6, click, double, element

I want to perform double click on an html element. I can click once, but can't double. I tried to move mouse on element, but couldn't find coordinates.

```
...
IE.Document.GetElementById(An & "q8").focus  
IE.Document.GetElementById(An & "q8").dblclick ' not working on hmtl  
...
```

I can't add, change etc. html codes. So I can't add or change events, attributes. I need to doubleclick on element directly, maybe mousemove and click or something like that.

Double click action selects a value from a popup list, and set it to a inputbox. Keystrokes not working. Client side changes are not applied. I tried to change input value, but when another element's value changes first one returns to original value.

(vb6 and ie8+)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546040/how-to-use-both-onclick-and-ondblclick-on-an-element

Comment: I can't add,change etc html codes. So i can't add or change events, attributes. I need to doubleclick on element directly.