# Apply multi-event do same function on same element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
button.onclick = function () {console.log("done");}; 
button.ondblclick = function () {console.log("done");};
```

If I want to decrease these lines and make them do the same function without any duplication, how can I do so?

I have a way:

```
function print ()
{
    console.log("click");
}

button.onclick = print;
button.ondblclick = print;
```

But I don't want to duplicate the calling of the function.
I was thinking something like this:

```
if (button.onclick == True  || button.ondblclick == True)
{
  console.log("done");
}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: `button.onclick = button.ondblclick = print`

Comment: You can but you can't avoid triggering click event on doubleclick.

Comment: dbl click will trigger the function 3 times. 2 times for each click and 1 time for dbl click

Comment: @AndrewLi how does your suggestion or the dupe address not duplicating the action? it's essentially the same thing the op says doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546040/how-to-use-both-onclick-and-ondblclick-on-an-element

Comment: if anything, question pointed out by @JohanKarlsson should be the duplicate

Comment: I wasn't care about onclick and ondblclick for precise, I meant any 2 events whatever they are
but you opened my mind to new information, many thanks